# Getting hundreds of import errors when running boilerplate code in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Recently I tried opening up Visual Studio 2019 because I wanted to try I new IDE when I was met with hundreds of errors upon running standard boilerplate c++ code. More specifically import errors. I have tried installing the newest version of Visual Studio, have tried adding the path manually to the "Additional Include Directories and modifying my installation but nothings worked.

**Update:** In the build errors I got the following error

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory

and when I checked the directory where I would expect the header file to be it wasn't there.

[image: Image of my application and errors]

Comment: When you installed, did you also install the C++ development tools? At least for a while there, the tools were optional, leading to problems like this and for all I know they may still be optional.

Comment: Nope still gives me the same errors but it also says i have the core c++ features installed so i dont think im missing any packages/components might be wrong tho

Comment: Next in the low-hanging fruit department: You're absolutely certain you've created a C++ project?

Comment: Right now you have a storm of intellisence errors. What happens when you build? If it fails, and it probably will, there might be some good information to be had in the output tab.

Comment: lol yeah i have tried empty projects, console applications and just running a bare cpp script but either way i still get like 500 errors

Comment: yeah now i simply get this error now "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory"

Comment: i now see that the header file is not in the expected path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um"

Comment: Someone who knows the VS build tools better than I can probably help you with that extra bit of information. I'd add it to the question to make it easier to find. I wonder if the u in um stands for universal? You could be trying to build a universal C++ project without the universal tools. Or the other way around. Lot of options in modern Visual Studio, and I use almost none of them.

Comment: Docs on that universal  stuff: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/universal-windows-platform-development-with-c/

Comment: Thanks for your help ill check that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.Check the C++ windows sdk version in VS Installer.**

[image]

**2.Make sure that the installed windows sdk is selected in your project properties.**
[image]

Comment: @Big Daddy  May I know if your problem has been solved?